# Nested if; how to proceed to the next elif from true if

Tags: python

I'm "learning python the hard way", my first programming language as well.
I'm trying to figure out how to go to next "elif" block from within the first "if" block.

I wrote a short example:

```
door = raw_input("> ")

if door == "1":
    door == "2"
elif door == "2":
    print "LOL Yeah."
```

Inside my actual code, inside the first "if" block I make another if\elif blocks, and inside one of them I want to set an if\elif condition that goes to the initial elif, i.e (elif door=='2')

In the short example above I want the output to be:

"> 1
LOL Yeah."

I'm sorry if that wasn't clear enough.

Comment: drop the `el` and just use a second `if`. `elif` means `else if` and the `else` implies it is only executed if the previous condition is found not to be true. When a branch in an `if/elif/else` statement is entered, none of its other branches will be entered.

Comment: This is a beginner's question and relatively well written, although trival to answer for most readers here. I find it inappropriate to just down-vote it without giving a hint on how he could improve it. @l4mpi: Why not give this as an actual answer?

Comment: @mbschenkel this is a very low-level question lacking research (e.g. reading the `if` documentation), I find it inappropriate to upvote it - and IMO it's even more inappropriate to base your voting on the OPs metadata like age/rep/gender instead of the actual content of the question. Read the description of the upvote/downvote arrows and reconsider if you'd really want to state that this question is well-researched, useful and clear. As to why I didn't post an answer, I'm not here for the rep and don't feel like promoting a question like this by posting an "official" answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
door = raw_input("> ")

if door == "1":
    door = "2"
if door == "2":
    print "LOL Yeah."
```

The `if/elif` is conditional. This means that if the first `if`-clause is executed, the `elif` is not reached.

Here's an example, I've wrapped your code in a function so you can test it more easily.

```
>>> def test_doors():
...     door = raw_input("> ")
...     if door == "1":
...         door = "2"
...     if door == "2":
...         print "LOL Yeah."
...         
...     
... 
>>> test_doors()
> 1
LOL Yeah.
```

Notice that you also have an error in your first `if`-clause, where you are attempting to set the value of `door` to `2`. You need to drop the second `=`, otherwise the variable is never changed. In fact, it is evaluated and the interpreter returns a `False` because it thinks you want to ask if `door` has the value of `2`. You can try this in the interpreter like so:

```
>>> door = 1
>>> door == 2
False
>>> door == 1
True
```